# avconv save 10 frames and update them in cycle

Tags: ffmpeg, avconv

The way I am saving frames from camera is:

```
avconv -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video0 -r 5 output_%04d.png
```

Seems to be working fine... but... I need to save only 10 frames and overwrite the saved first saved all the time... any way to do that? I need to be able to save frames and process them in other application... but process may take longer than record.

Tried to save one frame and overwrite it, but the problem is that file is being used and it simply doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

There's a roundabout way to do this. You can use the segment muxer. This doesn't support image sequences, though. So, the method is to encode using PNG codec in MOV files and then run a script to extract the PNG stream losslessly to the image format.

```
ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video0 -r 5 -c:v png
       -f segment -segment_time 0.1 -segment_wrap 10 out%d.mov
```

And then, iterate the command below for all 10 MOVs,

```
ffmpeg -i out1.mov -c copy out1.png
```